# After reopening application, multiple instances of a service are created

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-notifications

I am trying to create an application to update a persistent notification even while the app is closed. Right now, I'm using a service that is started in MainActivity's onCreate():

```
serviceIntent = Intent(this, PersistentService::class.java)
val stopped = stopService(serviceIntent)
println("[123] stopped: $stopped")
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    startForegroundService(serviceIntent)
} else {
    startService(serviceIntent)
}
```

This works perfectly to start it. However, when I reopen and close the app, even though stopped: true is printed, the previous service is still running and the previous service's stopService() was not called.

Stripped down version of the PersistentService class:

```
var timesStarted = 0
var lastService: PersistentService? = null

class PersistentService: Service(){
    private var timer: Timer? = null
    private var task: AsyncTask<*, *, *>? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        timesStarted++
        println("[123]starting persistent service. timesStarted: $timesStarted lastService===this: ${lastService===this} lastService==this: ${lastService==this} lastService: $lastService")
        println("[123] hashCode: ${hashCode()}")
        lastService = this
        if(timer == null){
            timer = Timer()
        }
        setToLoadingNotification()
        timer?.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask(){
            override fun run(){
                println("[123]Updating hashCode: ${this@PersistentService.hashCode()}")
                if(task?.status == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
                    // send notification saying last request timed out
                }
                task?.cancel(true)

                task = DataUpdaterTask(DatabaseDataRequester { GlobalData.connectionProperties }) { dataRequest ->
                    // send notification based on dataRequest value
                }.execute()
            }
        }, 1000L, UPDATE_PERIOD)
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun notify(notification: Notification){
        getManager().notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }
    private fun getBuilder(): Notification.Builder {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            return Notification.Builder(this, NotificationChannels.PERSISTENT_STATUS.id)
        }
        return Notification.Builder(this)
    }
    private fun getManager() = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    override fun stopService(name: Intent?): Boolean {
        println("[123]Stopping persistent service")
        timer?.cancel() // stop the timer from calling the code any more times
        task?.cancel(true) // stop the code from running if it's running
//        getManager().cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)
        return super.stopService(name)
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
[123] stopped: false
[123]starting persistent service. timesStarted: 1 lastService===this: false lastService==this: false lastService: null
[123] hashCode: 4008007
[123]Updating hashCode: 4008007
[123]Got successful data request
[123]Updating hashCode: 4008007
[123]Got successful data request
// *close and reopen the app*
[123] stopped: true
[123]starting persistent service. timesStarted: 2 lastService===this: false lastService==this: false lastService: me.retrodaredevil.solarthing.android.PersistentService@3d2847
[123] hashCode: 7823272
[123]Updating hashCode: 7823272
[123]Got successful data request
[123]Updating hashCode: 4008007
[123]Got successful data request
[123]Updating hashCode: 7823272
[123]Got successful data request
```

As you can see from the output, both services are running at the same time. The hashcode shows that they are not the same object so it wouldn't matter if I put my code in the onCreate() instead of onStartCommand() (I already tested this anyway)

It would be helpful if anyone could point me in the right direction. I am new to android development and I had trouble finding the correct way to do this. I'm not even sure if what I'm doing right now is the best way to update the notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and the previous service's stopService() was not called.

`stopService()` is not a lifecycle method of a `Service`. Perhaps you are thinking of `onDestroy()`.

> the previous service is still running

No, the previous service instance was stopped. You just leaked the `Timer`, because you did not cancel the `Timer` in `onDestroy()`.

So, override `onDestroy()`, put your `cancel()` calls in there, get rid of the rest of `stopService()`, and you should be in better shape.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works just as I intended it. I'll have to pay closer attention to the documentation next time, I'm sure I missed something.